# Python code to determine the tf-idf of each tweet from a .txt file

Tags: python, twitter, tf-idf

I was hoping if you'd be able to help me with a way to readlines in from a .txt file (treat these as individual documents) and determine the tf-idf of each tweet.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals 
import math
from textblob import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
    return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)

document1 = tb("""RT @brides: These are 5 hidden jobs no one one tells about one maids-of-honor one about. You're welcome: jobs http://t.co/qybBewFDre
This brides week on brides twitter: One new brides follower via http://t.co/0NP5Wz70Op""")

document2 = tb("""Python, from the Greek word (Ï€ÏÎ¸Ï‰Î½/Ï€ÏÎ¸Ï‰Î½Î±Ï‚), is a genus of
nonvenomous pythons[2] found in Africa and Asia. Currently, 7 species are
recognised.[2] A member of this genus, P. reticulatus, is among the longest
snakes known.""")

document3 = tb("""The Colt Python is a .357 Magnum caliber revolver formerly
manufactured by Colt's Manufacturing Company of Hartford, Connecticut.
It is sometimes referred to as a "Combat Magnum".[1] It was first introduced
in 1955, the same year as Smith & Wesson's M29 .44 Magnum. The now   discontinued
Colt Python targeted the premium revolver market segment. Some firearm
collectors and writers such as Jeff Cooper, Ian V. Hogg, Chuck Hawks, Leroy
Thompson, Renee Smeets and Martin Dougherty have described the Python as the
finest production revolver ever made.""")

bloblist = [document1, document2, document3]
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in document {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    for word, score in sorted_words[:3]:
        print("Word: {}, TF-IDF: {}".format(word, round(score, 5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

```
file_names = ['file1.txt','file2.txt']
#open files
files =  map(open,file_names)
#read files
documents = [file.read() for file in files]
#close files
[file.close() for file in files]
#create blobs
bloblist = map(tb,documents)
```

More about reading and writing files u can find here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

You can parse your strings from files like that:

```
example_string ="""Twitter feed 1: foo
Twitter feed 2: bar
Twitter feed 3: foobar
"""

#parsing using python string methods:
lines_list = example_string.split('\n')
for line in lines_list:
    msg_start_poz = line.find(':') + 1
    tweet_msg = line[msg_start_poz:]
    print tweet_msg

#using regular expressions
pattern = re.compile('^Twitter feed [0-9]+:(.*?)$',re.MULTILINE)
for tweet in re.finditer(pattern,example_string):
    print tweet.group(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But this does not solve my problem. Let me try again. I have twitter feeds in a .txt file that look like: Line 1 Twitter Feed 1 - @gracieataylor Come and find me Line 2 Twitter Feed 2 - #TempeChen FYI// Whooping cough bounces back AND another 1000+ such tweets.     
I am hoping to determine tf-idf of each tweet line by line.

Comment: Look here:https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods . If python standard string methods are not enought for you. U can use regular expressions and python re module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html